# Export data in an incoming email attachment with a specific subject to saved Excel file using Outlook VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

When a mail with a specific subject is received in Outlook, how can I transfer the data in the Excel file attached to an Excel file saved on the hard disk?

Is there an application or VBA example?

[Pull data from incoming mails with specific subject into Excel file using Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44497978/pull-data-from-incoming-mails-with-specific-subject-into-excel-file-using-outloo) transfers data in the mail body to the Excel file.

Answer (score 0):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide anything for reading attachments on the fly. You must save the attached file to the disk by using the [SaveAsFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment.saveasfile) method which saves the attachment to the specified path. Then you can automate Excel for reading the saved file and updating the other one.

The [Application.NewMailEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.newmailex) event from the Outlook object model fires once for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item. Use the Entry ID to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.